# sortorder in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

In the below example I get for the year in the second `\printbibliography`:

```
1960
1909a
1909b
```

Is it possible to get the a/b also changed?

```
1960
1909b
1909a
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,sortcites,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{yntd}{
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
        \literal{9999}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{vangennep:related, vangennep:trans, vangennep}
\printbibliography
\newrefcontext[sorting=yntd]
\cite{vangennep:related, vangennep:trans, vangennep}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: sure, but I asked how to get 1960 first and then 1909b ...

Comment: Sorry. I've got a small screen and couldn't see the first bit when thinking about it, so it seemed as if the question applied to the list beneath. Does the issue depend on starting a new reference context/sortcites/authoryear/hyperref/csquotes?

Comment: I think (but I'm not certain) there's a misconception here. I'm not sure because I don't know precisely when Biber/Biblatex does what. But the `a` and `b` aren't part of what is sorted because they aren't part of the entry data. They're rather identifiers added to get unique labels in citations. So I'm not sure these even exist when the entries are sorted.

Comment: If you look in the `.bbl`, you see that the year is always `1909`. There is no `a` or `b` to sort.

Comment: I know, But my question is if it is possible in any way or not??

Comment: I think you'd have to look at the way the suffixes are added to the labels, rather than how the entries are sorted?

Comment: The "a" and "b" are generated *based on* the sorted list. This is always done in a way that the one that appears first is "a", the next one "b" etc. etc. So this doesn't immediately appear easily possible.